# Jest Enzyme unit test axios api services with coverage

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, axios, enzyme

I'm new to jest, enzyme unit tests. I have the following code and it is working as expected

> Component

```
import productService from './../../../productService';

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.productService = new productService();
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.productService.getProductList().then(res => {
        if (res.status === "Success") {
            /// Some actions 
        } else {
            /// Some actions 
        }
    });
}
```

> productService.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

class productService {

    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            apiUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
        }
    }

    getProductList() {
        return axios.get(this.state.apiUrl + "products/listProducts")
            .then(res => {
                return res.data;
            }).catch(err => {
                return err;
            });
    }

}
export default productService;
```

and I have tried `axios-mock-adapter` for mocking the API and its response.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
describe('User List Component Unit Tests', () => {
    var mock = new MockAdapter(axios);

    mock.onGet("/products/listProducts").reply(200, {
        "status": "Success",
        "data": [...]
    });

    it('Should trigger the product list api', () => {
        wrapper.find('myComponent').instance().componentDidMount();

        axios.get("/products/listProducts").then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
});
```

So the test will run successfully but I can't see the coverage in the coverage report.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in your `getProductList()` you return `res.data` on successful fetch, and then in `componentDidMount()` you check if the `getProductList()`'s response status equals `'Success'`, so essentially what you're doing is this:

```
axios.get("/products/listProducts").then(res => {
    if (res.data.status==='Success') {...}
});
```

No wonder this path is never taken.

Comment: Yes, I have => expect(response.data.status).toEqual('Success'); . but if path is still not taken/covered. And my component if statement works fine. I'm facing the issue only with unit test coverage.

Comment: Didn't get the solution yet.